# Distributing App via client;s MDM solution

Tags: mdm

I have a customer that wants to distribute our non-public application via their internal application store.

I have attempted to sign the application for distribution as an "App Store" application and "Ad-Hoc" application, using our development account and profile, but keep having an issue with the provisioning certificate according to the user.

They have other applications that were deployed via the MDM and others just provided a signed IPA file. The client uses MAAS 360 as a MDM solution, does anyone know how to properly sign the application for distributing via MAAS360?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sign the app with 'Ad-Hoc' provisioning profile then it will be locked to the UDID's of the devices you have in the system. This should work just fine provided you:

- unlock the phone with XCode
- ensure same phone is part of the profile
- enroll that phone
- push the app

In order to push the apps to any device in the world via mdm you need the customer to be registered for ENTERPRISE developer program (this registration requires a DUNS number and costs 300 USD/year). Once you have that you will be able to create a provisioning profile that allows installation on any device.